# Need SQL Server SELECT To Return Previous Record Based On A DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I need to create a SQL Server 2012 `SELECT` statement that will give me the previous row in a table. I need to specify the current datetime and have the query return the closest previous datetime stored in the `[TargetDate]` column.

So in the table I may have...

```
[TargetUnit]    [TargetDate]
-----------------------------------
4               2015-12-09 10:15:00 
5               2015-12-09 10:30:00
8               2015-12-09 10:45:00
15              2015-12-09 11:00:00
22              2015-12-09 11:15:00
```

and I use the `GETDATE()` to query the `[TargetDate]` field. Say the current `GETDATE()` is `2015-12-09 10:37:00` - then I need the query to return the row with the `[TargetUnit]` of `5` and the `[TargetDate]` of `2015-12-09 10:30:00`.

Comment: Closest previous has `MAX(date)` among all `WHERE date < dateToCompareWith`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `top` and `order by` to get the desired record.

```
select top 1 [TargetUnit], [TargetDate]
  from tbl
 where [TargetDate] < GETDATE()
 order by [TargetDate] desc
```

Comment: Hi sstan, thanks for the help but this does not pay attention to the time.  When I do the less than datetime it returns date values for the previous day (2015-12-08)

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  It should work just fine.  I even checked in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03233/1).

Comment: This should work I agree as long as there aren't things that are future dates in the table the could be closer to GETDATE()

Comment: @WBratz: You would have to explain that.  The query filters out all dates that are in the future, so that would not be a problem.

Comment: @sstan It was specified  to find the CLOSEST date in a table. If the table has FUTURE dates in it they could be closer to GETDATE() than a date in the table that is a past. So for example if we have 10-10 as the getdate and the table holds 10-5 and 10-11 your query isn't going to find 10-11 since its future even though it is CLOSER to the get date. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @WBratz: OP said: _closest ***previous*** datetime_.

Comment: @sstan totally missed that, you win. I revert back to my first post that I agree your query would work as long as he's not looking for future dates.

Comment: @sstan, with the help of your SELECT statement I've found the needle in the haystack.  It looked like it should work and I was pulling my hair out knowing that it should.  I found the issue but your help brought me to it.  Thanks again!!  Also thanks WBratz.  You guys have helped me keep my job.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can do it using datediff and a while loop, I should say this is the best option I could think of if you're dealing with a table that could have FUTURE datetimes in it. This till find the closest value, future or past, to the specified date.

```
DECLARE @targetdate datetime
DECLARE @getdate datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @targetunit int

CREATE TABLE #diffs (targetunit int, targetdate datetime, diffday, diffsec int)

SELECT * INTO #table FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TABLE) > 0
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @targetunit = targetunit, @targetdate = targetdate FROM #table
DELETE FROM #table WHERE targetunit = @targetunit and targetdate = @targetdate

INSERT INTO #diff
SELECT @targetunit, @targetdate, datediff(day, @targetdate, @getdate),         Datediff(second, @targetdate, @getdate)
END

SELECT targetunit, targetdate, MIN(diffday) diffday, MIN(diffsec) diffsec
INTO #mins
FROM #diff 

SELECT *
FROM #diff a
JOIN #mins b on a.targetunit = b.targetunit
WHERE a.diffday = b.diffday and a.diffsec = b.diffsec
```